# Hosting an app from intranet via google apps

Tags: google-app-engine, proxy, reverse-proxy

Is it possible to create a google app engine program that would route http requests to a server on a local network?

What would be the best way to build a program like this?

I am trying to get away from buying a server from a hosting provider and simply use a local network server instead, and use google apps as a sort of proxy. The firewall would be configured to allow access to the server from the google app engine servers only.

If this has been done before in an open source project that would be excellent, but I have not been able to find one.

Comment: I don't understand what Google Apps (which, by the way, is completely different from Google App Engine) would have to do with anything here.

Comment: Why would you not just punch a hole in your firewall so HTTP requests can be made directly to the server you want to use?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is a domain name that points to your dynamic IP address, you could give Dynamic DNS a try. It's designed for your use case, and you won't need to write any code; you just need either a router that supports it or a server with `cron`. There are lots of providers, but I've had good experiences with [Dyn DNS](http://dyn.com/dns/), specifically their Remote Access plan.